# How do I mount a blank cd in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

Blank CDs do not mount in Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04). CDs with content do mount. 
I have a /media/cdrom0 directory and a /media/cdrom but when I enter this command:`~$ mount /media/cdrom0
I get:`mount: can't find /media/cdrom0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this :
`mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom0`

Comment: Hmmn ... I always thought that you have to have a file system first before you can mount something. A blank CD doesn't have a file system, hence, it sounds only logical that you cannot mount it.
Since USB's have become popular boot devices, I haven't used any CD's anymore. Don't shoot me if I'm wrong :)

Just to be curious... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jakke Yes, sorry, you are right. But i think, when you plug in CD, Ubuntu (Xubuntu) pops up a dialog.

Comment: @FilipSohajek udev recognizes that a blank CD is inserted and takes the necessary actions to ask whether you want to write data to your CD (if you have the proper software and hardware installed). It does not offer the option to mount a blank CD/DVD. The user always has the option to install a cd/dvd writer and manually start the software to edit the blank CD. This software will write straight to the block device, not to a mount point.

Comment: @Jakke I didn't say, that udev mounts blank CD.

Comment: Just trying to explain so the OP can understand what is going on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can not mount a blank CD, since it does not yet have a file system, unlike empty hard drives and USB flash drives. You need to write it using a specialized software, in Xubuntu, the default software is called Xfburn.